# Compiler Ginger Bread, build version codes Jelly Bean Mr1 cannot resolve or is not a field

Tags: android, eclipse, api

Question: What code should i use instead of
`if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1){ //perform something }`

1. Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1 error can not be resolved.
2. If compiled is set to Jelly Bean Mr1 and higher no errors. If compiler is set below Jelly Bean Mr1 errors occur.
3. minSdk = 9, targetSdk = 19, compiler = 2.3.1(Ginger Bread) see the below screen shot URL

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s283/sh/401b9ed5-d51d-4d55-b23d-6ebe8eeb8d03/212a791182b162df8dadb614445f2d2d

Answer (score 2):

if **Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1** gives a problem, only write:

```
import android.os.Build;
```

if you don't want to write it you can use

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
{ 
    //perform something 
} else {
    // perform other actions for other versions (below than jelly..)
    // find another way to do what you want.
}
```

if the problem persist maybe you don't have the necessary libraries, please update your libraries with Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

JELLY_BEAN_MR1 ~ Android 4.2
You should install and use Android 4.2 or higher as a compiler.

Comment: if i set compiler below Jelly Bean Mr1(Android 4.2) what should i do? Is there any other option please?